# How can I read the blog entries on my page in shopify

Tags: jquery, wordpress, content-management-system, shopify

Sorry for my weak technical language. I am playing with the Shopify and get stuck on an issue.

So, the issue is, I have some **blog** entries, say testimonials.
I am trying to display these testimonials on every **page**.

**this is my sample blog entries**

[image: sample blog entries]

**this is a page which will use the blog entries**

```
 {% for article in blog.articles %}
    <ul class="news">
        <li><span class="testimonial">"{{ article.content }}"</span>
        <p class="author">{{ article.title }}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
```

[image: some random page]

**I figure it out I cant access the blog on my page... when I try this code on the page to access the blog entries.. it did not work. but it is working if I use it on 'blog.xyz'**
[image]

> so my problem is, how can I read the blog entries on any page. 
>   I am thank full to all the developers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the testimonials in your custom page use this snippet (in the above example this should be placed in "page.rug-cleaning.liquid"):

```
{% for article in blogs.testimonials.articles %}
    <ul class="news">
        <li><span class="testimonial">"{{ article.content }}"</span>
        <p class="author">{{ article.title }}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Are you sure the handle of your "Testimonials" blog is "testimonials"? Can you see the testimonials on http://your-domain.com/blogs/testimonials ?

Comment: Try also using "blogs['testimonials'].articles" instead of "blogs.testimonials.articles".

Comment: looks like the blog handle is about-testimonials so should be `{% for article in blogs.about-testomonials.articles %}`

Comment: @bknights and @Stan Thank you so much, guys. It works with `{% for article in blogs.about-testimonials.articles %}`

Comment: @bknights, Pls post your solution so that I can mark it answer. :)

Comment: No worries. It is really @Stan 's answer. I just caught the handle name from your OP